# Debugging Electron renderer process through Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, electron, visual-studio-2019, attach-to-process

I have an Electron app that I'm debugging in VSCode. In my app, I create a `BrowserView` and load one of my websites: `browserView.webContents.loadURL(myUrl);`

Sometimes, I want to debug this website that's loaded in my `BrowserView`.

How I've been doing that is I open devtools in Electron and set breakpoints in the Chrome devtools that appears.

However, I wonder if I can spin up the localhost server from Visual Studio that hosts my website, and then debug my site directly from Visual Studio instead of through the devtools.

Is there a way to do this?

It seems like that won't work since the Visual Studio debugger is already attached and attaching it to the `BrowserView`'s renderer process didn't work, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Please try [this document's method](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/debug-instructions-windows). Hope it could help you.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I'm not trying to debug Electron. I'm trying to debug the site I have loaded into my renderer process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this? It seems like that won't work since the
> Visual Studio debugger is already attached and attaching it to the
> BrowserView's renderer process didn't work, but I wanted to check.

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want.**

**Actually** in Visual Studio, you cannot debug the renderer process. It does not support that. You have to use the Chrome devtools.

**Besides**, if you want this feature, you can suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) and hope the team will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll take your word for it. Seems like you have some affiliation with Microsoft.